# Cipher encrypting the same string to different string?

Tags: node.js, encryption

On registration I am encrypting the password and storing it in DB. On login, I am again encrypting the password and trying to match with the password in DB at the time of data retrieval as `SELECT * FROM table where uname=Username AND pwd=encryptedPasswd`. But the passwords are not matching even I entered same. How to resolve this? Below is my code. `pswd` in registration and `pswds` in login are not matching.

**Registration**

```
app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    // Assume I have a value in post.pwd
    var pswd = cipher.update(post.pwd, 'utf8', 'hex');
    pswd = "'" + pswd + cipher.final('hex') + "',";
    console.log(pswd);
    // Assume I have variable with value
    conn.query("INSERT INTO users VALUES (name, pswd)", function(err, rows, fields){
            if(!err){
                res.send(User);
            } else{
                console.log('Error while parsing the query...');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Login**

```
app.post('/login', function(req, res){


    var pswds = cipher.update(req.body.pwd, 'utf8', 'hex');
    pswds = "'" + pswds + cipher.final('hex') + "',";
    pswds = "'" + pswds + "',";
    console.log(pswds);

    var query = conn.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE phone='" + req.body.phone +
        "AND pwd='" + pswds + "'", function(err, rows, fields){
        const decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes192', 'encryptedpwd');
        var pswrd = decipher.update(rows[0].pwd, 'hex', 'utf8');
        pswrd = pswrd + decipher.final('utf8');
        pswrd = pswrd.substring(1, pswrd.length-2);
        if(!err && req.body.pwd == pswrd){
            res.send(rows[0]);
        } else{
            console.log('Error while parsing the query...');
        }
    });
});
```

Leave about the syntax, it is working fine. But both passwrods in registration and login are not matching even I entered correctly.

Comment: You should never encrypt your user's passwords. You need to use hashing instead with some strong ones being PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Since hash functions are one-way function, you won't be able to "decrypt" the hashes. In order to authenticate your user, you can run the password through the hash function again in order to compare with the hash that is stored in the database. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: Using hash also I have to do the same. I have to call hash.digest twice. If I do so, there will be an error. If I want to do, I have to call update also, that results different encrypted strings. Do answer to my question. Don't comment. @Artjom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the answer to my question. When someone face the above situation he just need to wrap up the encryption part in a function and then he has to call that function from different post calls. I changed the algorithm from aes192 to aes-256-gcm. 
Here is my code:

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
    algorithm = 'aes-256-gcm',
    password = '3zTvzr3p67VC61jmV54rIYu1545x4TlY', // must be 32-bytes
    // do not use a global iv for production, 
    // generate a new one for each encryption
    iv = '60iP0h6vJoEa'; // must be 16-bytes

var encryptText = function(text){
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, password, iv)
    var encrypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex')
    encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return encrypted;   
}
app.post("/register", function(req, res){
    var pswd = encryptText(req.body.pwd);
    console.log(pswd);
})
app.post("/login", function(req, res){
    var pswd = encryptText(req.body.pwd);
    console.log(pswd);
})
```

Now the passwords are matching in both cases. And the password must by 32-bytes and iv must be 16-bytes